# Is it possible to change the shape of Button control at runtime in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, button, runtime

I need to change the shape of Buttons which are added on runtime, Is it possible? How?

my css looks like

```
  button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }
```

But i want to change the shape of button to a ovel or pentagon

Comment: show me the code which you have written to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most likely you can select the control and apply css to it to change its appearance on the client (what I assume you meant by at runtime). If you have code, an example, I could provide.

Comment: I dont want to change just the appearance, i want or hcnage the shape of control, to to ovel or Pentagon..and i am adding these buttons dynamically so can not use Image button

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change using css.

```
Button btn= new Button();
bnt.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
```

and CssClass

```
  .button {
        background: url('/image/btn.png') no-repeat; 
            cursor:pointer;
            border: none;
    }
```

Comment: I want to change the shape of button to a ovel or pentagon, your code only changes the look of the button..kindly help

Comment: you need to add background property in css like this:- background: url('/image/btn.png') no-repeat;